# How to handle errors for strings in Go language

Tags: go

Implemented function words2numbers. example :input =seven six eight is passed through command-line arguments and output should be 768.

if input is seevn two fivee , then output needs to be  as invalid input.

Can anyone help me how to handle error in this case.

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    arr := os.Args[1:]
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        words2num(arr[i])
    }
}

func words2num(p string) {
    switch p {
    default:
        fmt.Println("invalid input")

    case "zero", "ZERO":
        fmt.Print(" 0 ")

    case "one", "ONE":
        fmt.Print(" 1 ")

    case "TWO", "two":
        fmt.Print(" 2 ")

    case "three", "THREE":
        fmt.Print(" 3 ")

    case "four", "FOUR":
        fmt.Print(" 4")

    case "five", "FIVE":
        fmt.Print(" 5")

    case "six", "SIX":
        fmt.Print(" 6 ")

    case "seven", "SEVEN":
        fmt.Print(" 7 ")

    case "eight", "EIGHT":
        fmt.Print(" 8 ")

    case "nine", "NINE":
        fmt.Print(" 9 ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a `default`  case to the `switch`, and have it print out the error message, or better yet: return the error

Answer (score 0):

As your code currently stands, it would probably be hard to do. But, the basic thing needed is to add a `default:` check in your `switch { ... }` that returns an error.

However, if the task is "print `invalid input` if the input is not valid" (and nothing else), you would need to change the signature of your decode function t return `(int, error)` (or a smaller integral type), accumulate the numbers in a slice, then print them. And if you ever have an error returned, skip to "print invalid input, then exit".

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is that whenever one of the strings provided in the input is incorrect the output should be `invalid input` and based on your current program it would print the output for all the strings.
You can concatenate the result of the function for every string and then print the result at the end.
A slightly modified version of your program:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    arr := os.Args[1:]
    result := ""
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        number, err := words2num(arr[i])
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        result += number
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func words2num(p string) (string, error) {
    switch p {
    case "zero", "ZERO":
        return "0", nil

    case "one", "ONE":
        return "1", nil

    case "TWO", "two":
        return "2", nil

    case "three", "THREE":
        return "3", nil

    case "four", "FOUR":
        return "4", nil

    case "five", "FIVE":
        return "5", nil

    case "six", "SIX":
        return "6", nil

    case "seven", "SEVEN":
        return "7", nil

    case "eight", "EIGHT":
        return "8", nil

    case "nine", "NINE":
        return "9", nil

    default:
        return "", errors.New("invalid input")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It worked .But one more challenge is  we have to run command in below format                 >>go run file.go "one two three"   Expected output : 123>>Now its giving Invalid input

Comment: You can use strings.Split to split your command line argument, something like this `arr := strings.Split(os.Args[1], " ")`